# How can I compute the correlation coefficient iteratively?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I'd like to compute the Pearson Correlation Coefficient (PCC) on-line i.e, deriving the PCC for n samples, then updating it with observation n+1.

Comment: You'll have to keep track of components of the PCC to be able to do it: $\sum x_i$ , $\sum y_i$ , $\sum x_i^2$, $\sum y_i^2$ and $\sum x_i y_i$.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. What is your approach?

Comment: You immediately have an iteration for the components: $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i = x_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ and likewise for the others.

Comment: ok I see I'd still have to compute the PCC using these components. I am looking for a way to compute it from the previous PCC.

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51622/combining-two-covariance-matrices/51927#51927) for a slightly more general answer or check the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Covariance).

Depending on the amount and type of data you would like to process this may be a numerically subtle problem.

Comment: pretty cool @gg thanks, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: @gg would you have any idea how fast this is in comparison to computing the PCC with all the observations?